# Insertar un elemento HTML cuando disparo el evento Submit

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero crear una TODO Card cada que dispare el evento Submit, pero al disparar el evento submit de nuevo, no me crea otra TODO Card sino que me edita el nombre de la TODO Card anterior. Como lograr que me cree una TODO diferente por cada vez que dispare el evento Submit.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
let input = document.getElementById('inputText');
let button = document.getElementById('inputButton');
let todoContainer = document.getElementById('todoContainer')

function pintar(todo){
    todoContainer.innerHTML = todo
}

//Enviar la informacion al formulario para agregarla en la todoapp
button.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(input.value)
    let todoValue = input.value
    //Imprimir una tarjeta con la tarea
    const article =`
        <article id="todo">
        <span>${todoValue}</span>
        <br>
        <label for="completedTask">Completed</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Completed" id="completedTask">
        <br>
        <label for="remainingTask">Remaining</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Remaining" id="remainingTask">
        </article>
    pintar(article)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

El [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) reemplazara lo que tengas dentro del elemento, por esa razón no se agregan nuevos.
Siguiendo la documentacion vemos que:

> Para insertar el código HTML en el documento en lugar de cambiar el contenido de un elemento, use el método insertAdjacentHTML().

```
function pintar(todo){
    todoContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",todo)
}
```

Puedes revisar algo más de información del [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Lo que te queda por mirar es como ir cambiando el id para no crear elementos con id duplicados y si vas a usar radiobutton que compartan el mismo name para que funcionen correctamente.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda. En cuanto a lo de los id duplicados, sería manejarlos con class?. Respecto a los radio button miraré la documentación porque realmente no sé muy bien como funcionan.